# Is it possible for me to set my boolean variable to true and false at the same time?

Tags: variables, boolean

The program I'm writing, or at least what I have written of it so far, really relies on this somehow working.

If anyone could come up with a direct solution that would be really appreciated, but if it's impossible (or at least really improbable) then I guess a workaround would work, but it would be extremely inconvenient to my work.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense. Can you post some example code that illustrates what you're trying to do?

Comment: Use an integer instead. 0 is false, 1 is true, 3 is like "true and false". Note that you will need to account for 3 in any if-statements.

Comment: Can't you use `null`?

Answer (score 1):

That sort of goes against the definition of a boolean.
You could create your own custom structure that can be any of 3 states instead.